# cross-compilation using mingw32 and gmp

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, gmp, mingw32

I am currently trying to cross-compile a c++ code I wrote which worked perfectly fine on Linux.

I installed mingw32, and compiled libgmp as a windows library ( .a ) using something like that :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/ --host=i586-mingw32msvc
```

Hope I did it right

I added two directories to my project incs and libs. In incs I put the .h header ( gmpxx.h ) and in libs I put libgmpxx.a and libgmp.a

I tried to compile using this makefile :

```
CPP=i586-mingw32msvc-g++
CPPSPECS=
LDFLAGS=-I incs/ libs/
EXEC=ceyd++.exe


all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): base64.o polynome.o chiffre.o dechiffre.o ceyd.o
    $(CPP) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) 

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) -o $@ -c $< $(CPPWARNINGS) $(CPPSPECS)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
    rm -rf $(EXEC)
```

I removed the warning part as it is not usefull here.

When i run make, it tells me that no gmpxx.h as been found....

Does anybody have a solution? Tried hard on this one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compile directive should point to the header directory 'incs' which it is not:

```
$(CPP) -o $@ -c $< $(CPPWARNINGS) $(CPPSPECS)
```

Create a variable as follows:

```
CCFLAGS=-Iincs/
```

and modify your compile directive:

```
$(CPP) -o $@ -c $< $(CPPWARNINGS) $(CPPSPECS) $(CCFLAGS)
```

Furthermore your LDFLAGS variable should look like:

```
LDFLAGS=-Llibs/ -l...
```

Where ... indicates the name of the shared library you're linking with in libs/. If you only have a static library (.a) add this to your linking directive.